# Query regarding Delete in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have group id column in database which has many same group id's with differnt model I'd in groups table as below.

```
Modelid    group id
  8                553
  10              553
   15             553
```

I want to delete all group id 553 in database.How to delete this?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Which tables / models have the group_id column?

Comment: Groups table has groupid column and same groupid will have multiple model I'd.

Comment: If you need to delete all Groups that have a group ID of 553, try Group.where(group_id: 553).delete_all

Comment: I need to delete all same groupid.

Comment: Ok thanks.I will check

Comment: I have total 20 same groupid. 553 .will it Delete all?

Comment: @AlexRoz yes say this is a join table we will call it `UserGroup` then `UserGroup.where(group_id: 533).delete_all` will delete all of those relationships. Please note that `delete_all` has no call backs (just pure SQL DELETE) so if you need destruction callbacks e.g. `(before/after)_destroy` then use `destroy_all` instead

Comment: Ok thanks.I will check.